# Is there a way to pass an open file to pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that is too large to read into memory all at once (~46 GB), and I want a subset of that data which can fit into memory.  I am able to read in part of the file, filter out what I do not want by doing an inner join with a previously created filtering index, and then continue on to the next part of the file like below:

```
    with open('Filtered_By_Month/all_data.csv','r') as f:
        cols=np.array(f.readline().strip('\n').split(','))#column names
        data=[]
        df=None
        for i in f:
            data.append(i.strip('\n').split(',')
            if len(data)==1000000:
                df_sub=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=cols).set_index('KEY_')
                df_sub=df_sub.join(filtered_keys,how='inner')
                data=[]
                if df is None:
                    df=df_sub
                else:
                    df=pd.concat([df,df_sub])
```

This seems to do the trick except it is extremely slow.  An alternative would be to use pandas read_csv function along with the nrows and skip_rows arguments, however this becomes really slow as well since each time I call the read_csv method, the file is reopened and the cursor is at the first line, and I have to iterate through the lines until I have gone past skip_rows.  Is there a way to combine both of these methods so that I pass a file to read_csv that is already open and thus I do not need to have the cursor start all over again.

Comment: `pd.read_csv` has a `nrows` option. I believe you case can be done with `pd.read_csv('file.csv', nrows=1000000)`.

Comment: `read_csv` does accept a file-like object, per the docs.

Answer (score 0):

## Narrow answer: yes

You can provide the `engine='python'` and `nrows=N` arguments to pick up where pandas's reader leaves off in a text file, or to use `pd.read_csv` multiple times for a single open file object.

Pandas searches the file for separators such as commas newlines. By default (based on your provided arguments), pandas uses an optimized C-compiled reader that is faster, but has fewer features. Using this reader, the cursor object is not always left at the end of the last-read line, and sometimes exhausts the file reader, other times it is left in the middle of the next line.

Using a simple ~200MB text file with two columns and 1,000,000 rows:

```py
In [10]: # create some data
    ...: pd.DataFrame(
    ...:     {'A': np.arange(0, 1e6), 'B': np.arange(1e6, 0, -1)}
    ...: ).to_csv('sample.csv', index=False)
```

We can see that reading all but the last two lines with the `engine='C'` parser leaves the cursor at the end of the file (nothing gets printed):

```py
In [11]: %%time
    ...: with open('sample.csv', 'r') as f:
    ...:     top = pd.read_csv(f, nrows=999998, header=0, engine='c')
    ...:     print(f.read())

CPU times: user 130 ms, sys: 2.99 ms, total: 133 ms
Wall time: 132 ms
```

With `engine='python'`, the file object is left at the end of the line, and we can read the remainder of the file, or make another `pd.read_csv` call:

```py
In [12]: %%time
    ...: with open('sample.csv', 'r') as f:
    ...:     top = pd.read_csv(f, nrows=999998, header=0, engine='python')
    ...:     print(f.read())
999998,2
999999,1

CPU times: user 2.86 s, sys: 150 ms, total: 3.01 s
Wall time: 2.96 s
```

However, the python reader is significantly slower.

## Better answer: don't

Providing `chunksize` as an argument to `pd.read_csv` will return an iterator.

From the pandas docs on [IO tools: Iterating through files chunk by chunk](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk):

> By specifying a `chunksize` to `read_csv`, the return value will be an iterable object of type `TextFileReader`

Using this chunked read mode allows us to return to using the C engine. With the example from above:

```py
In [13]: %%time
    ...: reader = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', chunksize=100000, header=0, engine='c')
    ...: for chunk in reader:
    ...:     tail = chunk.iloc[-2:]
    ...: print(tail)
             A  B
999998  999998  2
999999  999999  1
CPU times: user 136 ms, sys: 9.86 ms, total: 146 ms
Wall time: 146 ms
```

We're now barely slower than the C parser without chunking, even for 10 iterations on a pretty small file. As this file becomes larger than memory, using chunked reads will significantly outperform any pure-python file handling.

You can use this chunked read method to filter your data:

```py
reader = pd.read_csv('Filtered_By_Month/all_data.csv', chunksize=1000000)

chunks = []

for chunk in reader:
    # filter data
    filtered = do_something(chunk)
    chunks.append(filtered)

df = pd.concat(chunks)
```

## Alternatives: parallel frameworks

If you're working with a file that is significantly larger than memory, you may want to look at a parallel computing library such as Dask.

Dask has [tools for reading in CSV data](https://examples.dask.org/dataframes/01-data-access.html) using multiple threads, processors, or even servers. There is a performance overhead associated with spreading tasks across processors or through a network, but for sufficiently large tasks the gains will be worth it. There's also a learning curve, but some great work in aligning the dask.Dataframe API with pandas has brought the learning curve way down, so following the tutorials on the dask website should get you up and running pretty quickly.